# One to Many model in MongoDB for a movie ticket booking app

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, postman, mongoose-schema

I have been creating a movie booking app and I'm new to developing web apps. I am wondering on how to create a model for the same. For my condition, a movie can be showed in different locations. So I have given a location array in the movie model. I would also be able to sort based on locations. So I have created a location schema and a movie schema and referred the location schema inside movie schema. I'm giving the code snippet below.

**Movie Schema**

```
const movieSchema = new Schema ({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    language: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    format : {
        type: String,
        enum: ["2D", "3D"],
        required: true,
        default:"2D"
    },
    rating : {
        type: Number
    },
    location: [locationSchema]

})
```

**Location Schema**

```
const locationSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
    }
});
```

I have created a post method to create a movie record in the database with express.

**Post Method**

```
const router=express.Router();
const {Movie}=require ('../models/movie');
const {Location}=require('../models/locations')


router.post('/', function (req,res) {
    let body= req.body;

    let movie = new Movie (body)
    movie.save().then(function (movie) {
            res.send(movie)

    }).catch (function(err) {
        res.send(err)
    })
})
```

I have created the object as shown below to post from postman tool.

```
First Post Request
{

    "name":"Frozen 2",
    "language":"English",
    "rating":4,

    "location":[{
        "name":"Chennai"
    }, {
        "name":"Bangalore"
    }]
}

Another Post Request

{

    "name":"Aladdin",
    "language":"English",
    "rating":4,

    "location":[{
        "name":"Bangalore"
    }]
}
```

My first post request goes fine. But when adding a different movie entry, I am getting the "E11000 duplicate key error collection" for location as the location already exists. I dont know how to proceed further.

Comment: This code cannot generate that error. Location is just an embedded schema. Are you sure you posted the code you got that error. This code  must work.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like once the location has been added once for a movie, the same location cannot be added again for a different movie. Your thoughts please. Thanks